# How do I Select user_ID from one table and insert into another while searching by a variable? Python my SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert, where-clause

I am relatively new to programming and SQL in general.
So I am creating a system where users can log in and input events into a calendar and see them displayed.
To do this I create a table of `users` which registers the user's username and password and assigns them an ID on registration. I then made a second table for `events` where I wanted to list off all the events. However, I need to insert records into the events table, but one attribute is a `User_ID` field from the `users` table so that I can sort it by ID later.

My two tables were set up in phpmyadmin, through the wamp server, but the creation and queries are done in the code. I've looked for relating problems but have found no solutions

Anyways, I need to make a select statement which is like:

```
query = """SELECT ID FROM users2 where name = '%s'"""
```

(name is a column in the table for username)

(`%s` would be the username for the user.)
and then input this into the other table like so:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO events 
    (userID, Event_Name, Event_Date, Priority)
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (user_ID, name_of_event,
     Event_Date, priority_number))
```

(at this point `user_ID` is basically undefined. Do I define `user_ID` as = `cursor.execute(query)`?)

I need help getting the `user_ID` and performing this select statement in the first place since I keep getting 0 as the value. Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: It is entirely unclear (to me) what you are looking for. Could you post a sample input and output? Also, remember: you don't have to do everything in one query, and you don't have to do everything on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `insert ... select`:

```
insert into events (userid, event_name, event_date, priority)
select id, %s, %s, %s
from users2
where name = %s
```

This filters `users2` by `name`. Then for each match, a row is inserted in `events`, with the corresponding `userid` and three literal, constant, values for the three other columns.

You would pass the parameters to the query in the following order:

```
 name_of_event,
 event_date, 
 priority_number,
 user_name
```

Note that if you want to do this consistently, you would probably need to set up a `unique` key on `users2(name)`, so the filtering by name is unambiguous.

Comment: query = """INSERT INTO events (userID, Event_Name, Event_Date, Priority)
  SELECT ID, %s, %s, %s
  FROM users2
  WHERE name = %s""", (name_of_event, Event_Date, priority_number, name_of_user)
 cursor.execute(query)                 gives me a 'TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes error' and when I do cursor.execute(query, name_of_event, Event_Date, priority_number, name_of_user) I receive a .TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given. error, so what do I do now?

Comment: I've also tried cursor.execute(query ,(name_of_event, Event_Date, priority_number, name_of_user)) but no record is inserted into the table.